# In python3, dict.items() returns items in different order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am porting my code from python2 to python3, but having problem with common function which lists the web page elements in order. In python2 it returned a different order, and my code was using by index, so now they are breaking. How can I fix this

Basically, in python2,

```
myDict = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}
print (myDict.items())
```

[('Three', 3), ('Two', 2), ('One', 1)]

In python3,

```
myDict = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}
print (list(myDict.items()))
```

[('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]

Why is there this difference and how can I fix it? Do I just reverse the list or is there a better fix? thanks!

Comment: In Python 2 your code was broken.

Comment: Dicts are not ordered. Thats why you can't say dict[0] to get the first element.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered data structures, you shouldn't have relied on that to begin with.

Comment: Check out this post as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: Have you tried using an ordered dict or considered sorting the dict by key/value?